# Any rules/conventions on using "dashed" and "dotted" hyperlinks?

Tags: css, webforms, hyperlink, styling

Recently I've seen a wide usage of dotted and dashed hyperlinks in a variety of Russian Web 2.0 websites. Normally such links (which have a dashed or dotted line underneath them, instead of a normal solid line) don't lead a user to another page, but rather perform an action on the same page without reloading it.
As an example, such links can fold/unfold information blocks, or switch between sorting order of page elements.

So I'm wondering: are such links used in the same way in the bigger internet?
Also, are there any articles or books which describe standard look&feel for hyperlinks depending on the action they perform?

Comment: At least here in Brazil, this is not widely use... Although I've seen it in a couple of sites

Comment: @esnyder I have only examples for Russian websites. E.g.: http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/business-lynch/2011/04/06/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  I viewed the page you linked, but I only see "normal" links that all seem to reload the page.  The only thing that I can relate to what you were saying would be friendly URLs (like the URL to this question "any-rules-conventions-on-using-dashed[...etc]) or using the ./.. relative path marker (ie: mysite/images/../blog/my-blog-here)

Comment: @esnyder It's in the center of the page (right above the remote control picture). The link's underlining is dashed and clicking on it displays some additional text block.

Comment: Oh, I see!  That's just changing the link styling with a normal Javascript onclick.

Comment: This should probably be moved to UserExperience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a time, way back in the day, when a few folks tried to stick with the idea that dashed underlines were for contextual help. I think that was a carry over from old Windows help files.

But, since then, no, there is no rule or standards as to what the style of underline means in a hyperlink. For better or worse, the underline, itself, isn't even a standard anymore as lots of sites forgo them (which, IMHO, is more often than not a bad idea).

All that said, I do like the idea and the attempt and differentiating on-page interaction vs. a link that actually takes you somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I guess then, that would be the answer. There's currently no standard on that. Also, as a summary: in Russian websites, dashed links perform some action on the same page and don't take a user somewhere else. And dotted links, in turn, are historically used to mark an acronym (and supposedly show the information about the acronym on hover).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a matter of style and taste.

Personally, I wouldn't do it. Traditionally, hyperlinks are blue and underlined (or get underlined on mouseover). It helps the users navigate swiftly through the page without thinking much. If you have your links green and overlined, it works just as well but in my opinion, it's less user-friendly (for a new visitor).
Unless it has a special meaning on your site, of course.

The dotted underline is -as far as i know- traditionally used for the `acronym` tag.

Comment: Well, as I said, I've seen dashed underlining on a lot of Russian websites. And it really works fine, since it notifies the user that this is not a real hyperlink, but is rather an action on the same page. But you may be right in that it's not what users in the English internet are used to. That's, actually, what I'm trying to find out :)

Comment: That's what I meant with "_unless it has a special meaning on your site_". I'm not really a part of the english internet but I'm not used to it either.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following in the CSS of the page -

```
border-bottom: 1px dashed #05C;
```

It's just a style override for the default  underlining.

Comment: Hmm... What's the question?  The use of Javascript onclick events to change formatting is widely used all over the internet to expose/hide/modify existing content on a page.

Comment: The question was: when do you use normal links and when do you use dashed/dotted links? Is there any standard way of distinguishing between them? And it seems that there's only a standard for dashed links in the Russian internet, and dotted links mark acronyms. See the answer which is marked as accepted.

Comment: I see!  Interesting.  I didn't honestly know there was a common difference other than the taste of the designer. ;)

Answer (score -1):

The normal format for hyperlinks is 'http://web.site.com/path/to/my/content?arg=value&arg2=value2#hashtag'. For relative links, parts of the URL are optional.

Technically, dots and dashes are acceptable in almost every part of a URL. It is unusual to see dots in the path, but dashes are quite normal (see the URL for this page, for instance). Dots and dashes are both uncommon in query parameters (the arg=value part), but should work. It is very common to see both dots and dashes in the hashtag, which is what I believe you were referring to.

The purpose of the hashtag is traditionally to link to a location within a web page, marked by an anchor tag () with a name attribute. In modern webapps, the hashtag is used as a 'bookmark' for a particular view in the app -- in GMail, for instance, the hashtag is used to mark which label and message you are viewing. There is no established norm for what is an appropriate hashtag. You should use whatever makes sense for your app. A human-readable tag is usually preferable, as it gives the user a better understanding of what the URL means, but it is certainly not required.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, probably this is my fault. What I meant is the appearance of the link on a webpage. Like, instead of the line underneath, there's a dashed or dotted line.